# Choosing the proper optimisation algorithm in R

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to find extremum of a linear objective function with linear equality, linear inequality and nonlinear (quadratic) inequality constraints. The problem is I have already tried many algorithms from packages like nloptr, Rsolnp Nlcoptim and for every time I have obtained different results. What is more the results differ (in many cases) from GRG algorithm from Excel which can find better results in terms of the minimising objective function.

So far solnp (Rsolnp package) gives some good results and after proper calibrating the results are even better than the one from GRG Excel algorithm. Results from Solnl (NlcOptim) are average and very different, even if the data input is slightly changed.
Nloptr (Nloptr package) function has implemented various number of algorithms. I tried few (I do not remember which exactly) and the results were still average and completely different than the one obtained so far from other algorithms.

My knowledge about optimisation algorithms is really poor and my attempts are rather based on a random selection of algorithms. Thus could you advise some algorithms implemented in R that can handle such problem? And which one (and why) is better from another? Maybe there is some framework or decision tree regarding choosing proper optimisation algorithm.

If this can help, I try to find the optimal weights of the portfolio assets, where the objective function is to minimise portfolio risk (standard deviation), with all assets weights sum up to 1 and are greater then or equal to 0, and with defined portfolio return as constraints.

Comment: Take a look at [CRAN Task View: Optimization and Mathematical Programming](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html).

Comment: I suspect you modeled things wrong. Minimizing risk yields a quadratic objective and linear constraints. This is convex (there are some rare numerical exceptions), so solvers should have no problem finding a global optimum.

Comment: This is too broad a question to answer. It would be better if you could post your mathematical model you need to optimize.